# Locally weighted regression vs. splines

Tags: regression, kernel-smoothing, smoothing, splines, loess

What's the pros/cons of splines approaches compared to locally weighted regression approaches for the purposes of (a) scatter plot smoothing and (b) prediction?

Obviously, in the case of prediction I assume that I have some "prior" that the data is smooth in some sense (otherwise, it makes no sense to use either of these techniques).

Initial discussion in [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205178/difference-between-local-regression-and-moving-average-for-smoothing/205197?noredirect=1#comment389474_205197).

Comment: Splines has the advantage that they can simply be used as basis function in usual multiple linear regression.